# new to java - Class<?> does not accept generic classes

Tags: java, android

I created the following method:

```
public  void getClasses (  Set<Class<?>>param )
{
}
```

in my main, I created the following :

```
Set<PupilVO> hold = new TreeSet<PupilVO>();
getClasses(hold);  <-- this gives a error
```

The error i get is:

```
The method `getClasses(Set<Class<?>>)` in the type test1 is not applicable for the arguments (`Set<test1>`)
```

test1 is the name of my class which I am doing all my code in ...

Here is what my [PupilVO class](http://mrbool.com/what-is-deep-copy-and-shallow-copy-in-java/28569) looks like.

If my limited understanding is correct, `Set<Class<?>>` means i can pass in a
Set of any kind of class i wish... if that is true, then why do I get an error?

Comment: Please post your `PupilVO` class, dont expect us to follow links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having this issue because the method `getClasses` expects a set of `Class` objects, in your code you're passing a set of `PupilVO` objects

Comment: can you tell me what is a Class object ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html here you go. You don't need it for your exercise though.

Answer (score 0):

`PupilVO` is not of type `Class<?>` so you get this compilation error.

If you want to pass a `Set` of any kind to your method, declare it like this:

```
public void getClasses(Set<?> setOfAnyObjects)
```

Comment: can you tell me what is Class<?>   ?